# Where magento 2 render the url for products and catalog?

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I would like to app prefix like my-product to the view product, for example using magento 2 sample product we can view one of the product using this link :

`http://localhost:8000/desiree-fitness-tee.html`

I would like to add `my-product` before `desiree` so it becomes :

`http://localhost:8000/my-product/desiree-fitness-tee.html`

I can do the *hack way* to achieve this, like change the `request_path` column in the table `url_rewrite`. But I'm pretty sure this is not the right way to do it.

So what I want to do is finding the module that generate all this url for products and categories, so I can add a prefix to that url before magento 2 render or showing the page.

Where can I find the module that handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Module that displaying or getting the url you can find it on :

- `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php`
- `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php`

Both of them has the method called `getRequestPath()`. You can change the behavior using [Plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods) in magento 2. Note use after for changing the return value of this method.